# Is this an appropriate use of ContT?

Tags: haskell, monads, continuations

I'm working on a project that requires me to write a small interpreter. The instructions have a simple tree structure and one of the commands has the effect of halting execution. So in the example below, "baz" is never printed.

```
import Control.Monad.Cont

data Instruction = Print String | Halt | Block [Instruction]
    deriving (Eq, Show)

instructions =
  [ Print "foo"
  , Block
    [ Print "bar"
    , Halt
    ]
  , Print "baz"
  ]

main :: IO ()
main = runContT (callCC $ interpret instructions)
                (const $ pure ())

interpret []     k = pure ()
interpret (a:as) k = case a of
    Print str -> liftIO (putStrLn str) >> interpret as k
    Block ins -> interpret ins k       >> interpret as k
    Halt      -> k ()
```

This is the first time I've seen a potential use for `ContT` in one of my projects. I was wondering if this is an appropriate use of it or if there is a simpler solution I might be overlooking.

Comment: If your only jumping instruction is `Halt`, you could do something simpler using `Except`. Apart from that, the continuation monad isn't a bad fit for interpreters in general.

Comment: This is fine. If we never have to change `k`, as done above, we could try using `traverse_` or `mapM_` over the whole list. Note that `k ()` is the same of `k () >> ...` because of the "early return" effect, so traversing the whole list (lazily) should be equivalent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this looks to be precisely the sort of use case for which `Control.Monad.Cont` is appropriate.

You are almost certainly aware of this, but for other readers, it's worth spelling out that if you'd written `interpret` so that it was a function from a list of instructions to an `IO ()` like so:

```
main :: IO ()
main = interpret instructions

interpret :: [Instruction] -> IO ()
interpret []     = pure ()
interpret (a:as) = case a of
    Print str -> putStrLn str >> interpret as
    Block ins -> interpret ins >> interpret as
    Halt      -> pure ()
```

then `foo` `bar` and `baz` all would have printed. What you needed was an escape mechanism that would allow you to abort the entire computation and immediately return a value. This is precisely what `callCC` provides. Calling the named computation (`k` in your code) allows you to escape out of the whole computation, not just that level/layer.

So good job, you've found precisely the appropriate use case for ContT here, I believe.